# Calling a UDF within another UDF

Tags: excel, vba

I need to call a previously made UDF, from another module (in the same workbook), to build another UDF. How do I call the first function?

This is for Excel VBA. I've already built my first function, which calculates the book value of a product at a specific time. It's in a module called 'BookValue' and the function is called 'BookVal'. I tried calling it in the next function as an application using Application.BookVal(args), as a UDF using UDF(), most recently by typing NewFunction = BookValue(BookVal) then the next steps.... nothing's worked. All return #VALUE.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Function BookVal(UseLife As Single, ResaleAge As Single, PurchPrice As Double, SalVal As Double) As Double


BookVal = PurchPrice - ((PurchPrice - SalVal) / UseLife) * ResaleAge


End Function

Function PostTaxSale(UseLife As Double, ResaleAge As Double, TaxRate As Double, ResaleVal As Double, PurchPrice As Double, SalVal As Double, BookVal As Double) As Double


PostTaxSale = BookVal(UseLife, ResaleAge, PurchPrice, SalVal)
PostTaxSale = ResaleVal - PostTaxSale
PostTaxSale = Tax * PostTaxSale
PostTaxSale = ResaleVal - PostTaxSale

End Function
```

This results in #VALUE

But I want the code to pull from selected cells as arguments and return the result of the equation:
After-tax Resale Value = Resale Value - Tax *(Resale Value - Book Value).

Comment: Can you post the other udf?

Comment: Also change everything to double including the currency.

Comment: I posted both UDF's. I've only created one, BookVal. And do you mean I should change everything in both UDF's to double?

Comment: I do not see BookValue.  I see two of the same PostTaxSale.

Comment: And yes including the function so that it returns a double: `Function BookValue(...) As Double`

Comment: Oh man, my bad. Fixed now.

Comment: When you call the function, unless they are optional one must provide all the criteria.  Your BookVal function requires 4 inputs, you are only giving one.  and check the spelling.  You are calling `BookValue` but your Function is called `BookVal`

Comment: I did that under the impression that I had to call the module, and then put the function in parenthesis (as these UDF's are in separate modules). I edited the second one, like you suggested, and it's still not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: put them in the same module?

Comment: Just did. Getting the same result when I use the PostTaxSale function. Updated my code in the original post.

Comment: Did you try my answer?  can you provide the values and the formula you used to call the udf?

Comment: I used: `=PostTaxSale(70,15,0.05,300000,250000,310000)` and got an answer.

Comment: Actually, just copied and pasted your answer it and it worked fine.... Thanks so much! What is different between your answer and the code I have in my question (now), though? (mine wasn't even working when I had all Doubles, so couldn't be that)

Comment: I omitted the `BookVal As Double` in the function criteria.  If that worked please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide all criteria being asked:

```
 Function BookVal(UseLife As Double, ResaleAge As Double, PurchPrice As Double, SalVal As Double) As Double 
     BookVal = PurchPrice - ((PurchPrice - SalVal) / UseLife) * ResaleAge
 End Function

 Function PostTaxSale(UseLife As Double, ResaleAge As Double, TaxRate As Double, ResaleVal As Double, PurchPrice As Double, SalVal As Double) As Double
    PostTaxSale = BookVal(UseLife, ResaleAge, PurchPrice, SalVal)
    PostTaxSale = ResaleVal - PostTaxSale
    PostTaxSale = TaxRate * PostTaxSale
    PostTaxSale = ResaleVal - PostTaxSale    
 End Function
```